# Let $G$ is a group and $x,y\in G$ then $y\in Cl_{G}(x)\Leftrightarrow x\in Cl_{G}(y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-actions

Let $G$ is a group and $x,y\in G$ then $y\in Cl_{G}(x)\Leftrightarrow x\in Cl_{G}(y)$.

Let $Cl_{G}(x)=\left \{ gxg^{-1}:g\in G \right \}$ and $Cl_{G}(y)=\left \{ hyh^{-1}:h\in G \right \}$ ($h,g\in G$).

Suppose $y\in Cl_{G}(x)$ then there exists $ x\in G$ such that $y=gxg^{-1}$. But from here I couldn't get $x=hyh^{-1}$ which means $x\in Cl_{G}(y)$

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: From the equation $y = gxg^{-1}$, can you write $x$ in terms of $y$?

Comment: Also, the correct way of writing those sets would $$\operatorname{Cl}_G(y) = \{hyh^{-1} : h \in G\}.$$

Comment: Solve the equation $y = g x g^{-1}$ for $x$.

Comment: just curious, what does $\text{Cl}_G(x)$ stand for?

Comment: I find this problem strange, because normally one proves that conjugacy is an equivalence relation before defining conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Aryaman's comment: Take $y \in \text{Cl}_G(x)$. Then there exists $g \in G$ such that $y = gxg^{-1}$. Now multiply this expression from the left with $g^{-1}$ and from the right with $g$. You get $x = g^{-1}yg$. If you let $h := g^{-1}$, you now clearly see that $x \in \text{Cl}_G(y)$, since $h^{-1} = (g^{-1})^{-1} = g$.